# How to replace LD variable in a Makefile to link C objects

Tags: c, makefile, ld

I'm writing a Makefile for C. I want be able to specify different programs for compilation and linking via environmental variables. However, I want it works without any additional variables too. I was trying to link with ld. However, the default doesn't link with standard C library.

The question:
**How to link C program with ld or $LD**
Is it possible to get appropriate flags from cc?

**I cannot use `$(CC)` in place of `$(LD)`. The `LD ?= cc` doesn't work too.**

I want something like this to be true:
Environment variable CC set to tcc.
Environment variable LD unset.
My Makefile compile using tcc and link using system default linker for C.

Unfortunately, some C compilers are unable to link some libraries. I have this problem with tcc and glfw.

P.S.
Linux user

Comment: I wasn't aware that Make had a variable called `LD`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditional assignment *$(LD) ?= cc* can not work, since $(LD) is predefined.

If you want to start make without predefined variables, use the option -R:

```
   > make -p | grep LD
   ... 
   LD = ld
   ...
   > make -p -R | grep LD
   >
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using ld as the linker, use gcc or g++. They add the appropriate command line options for getting libraries and startup code, etc. In other words:

```
ld -o main main.o
```

is equivalent to:

```
gcc -o main main.o
```

except that gcc adds all the command line parameters when it calls ld.

In other words: LD=gcc.

Comment: How to write in Makefile something like this:
`if (is_unset($(LD)))
LD = gcc
endif`

Comment: You shouldn't use `$(LD)` when linking a C program. You should use `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS)` instead.

Comment: `LD ?= gcc` doesn't work for me. The $(LD) is set to ld by default.

Comment: @Lars Wirzenius It doesn't work for some libraries if $(CC) == tcc

Comment: @Michas, you should probably figure out why not, in that case.

Comment: @Lars Wirzenius It isn't possible to fix every library or linker. It may be lack of time, sources or programming skills. I'm looking for a way around.

Comment: can you link with "cc" instead then instead of $(CC) ?

Answer (score 2):

One of the main features of [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) is that :

> *tcc* is a compiler **and** a linker [...] it compile and execute C source directly. No linking or assembly necessary

There's more detail in [tcc documentation](http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#SEC16), it says about linking that :

> Dynamic ELF libraries can be output but the C compiler does not generate position independent code (PIC). It means that the dynamic library code generated by TCC cannot be factorized among processes yet.

It means that, if you want to use tcc, you'll need to link with tcc.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you can define rule-dependent values for variables.

```
build_with_tcc: CC=tcc compile_tcc

compile_tcc:
    ## Commands to do a full build with tcc.

build_with_gcc: CC=gcc LD=g++ link_gcc

compile_gcc:
    ## Commands to compile with gcc.

link_gcc: compile_gcc
    ## Commands to link with g++.
```

And build it by calling the appropriate rule.

If you wish, in other hand, to be able to pass an arbitrary compiler toolchain, you will have to have some resctrictions anyway.

The rule:

```
build_with_arbitrary: compile_arbitrary link_arbitrary
```

Implies that your build must be done in two steps and the respective rules (`compile_arbitrary` and `link_arbitrary`) must obey the same commandline.

So you can invoke `make` with custom `CC` and `LD` variables:

```
CC=any_cc LD=any_ld make build_with_arbitrary
```

Lastly, you can add a dirty check for `LD` being empty in the linker step, and only perform it if not.

```
link_arbitrary:
    [ -n "$(LD)" ] && do_linker_stuff
```

So you could use `build_with_arbitrary` even for a compiler that does everything in a single step just by passing:

```
CC=any_cc LD= make build_with_arbitrary
```

I hope to have correctly understood your question. Sorry if I misunderstood, and please tell me were I am wrong.